# How to sort items of recycerview according to external conditions

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a simple app where user set their DOB and the app calculates the days remaining for next birthday.
I am using firebase to store data and when fetching data I get DOB from database and perform calculation to find days remaining for next birthday. Just for note days remaining is calculated after fetching it is not stored in database.
So what I want is After fetching DOB and calcultaing remaing days I want to show the data in Recycler View in the ascending order of the remaing days.
How can I do that?

`Databasemodel.kt`

```
data class Databasemodel(val uid:String, val name:String, val dob:String) {

constructor():this("",",","")
}
```

`Mainactivity.kt`

```
lateinit var bdayList: MutableList<Databasemodel>  //I have initialized it later
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BirthdayPersons")
  ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                bdayList.clear()
                for (iterator in p0.children) {
                    val bday=iterator.getValue(Databasemodel::class.java)
                    bdayList.add(bday!!)
                }
                row_recycle_actual.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
                row_recycle_actual.adapter=RecyclerAdapter(bdayList)
            }

        }

    })
```

Comment: Please post the code, where you have populated your `RecyclerView` `Adapter` with the data ie. your list of `DatabaseModel`

Comment: @ravi ok I have added some codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
for (iterator in p0.children) {
  val bday=iterator.getValue(Databasemodel::class.java)
  bdayList.add(bday!!)
}
```

you should sort the list by desired predicate, you may do it with sortBy in Kotlin:

```
//assuming you have "remainingDays" or similiar field in your model
bdayList.sortBy { dbmodel -> dbmodel.remainingDays}
```

then you may pass it to the RecyclerView

```
row_recycle_actual.adapter=RecyclerAdapter(bdayList)
```

Comment: I haven't noticed the Db model in the first place... in constructor of your dbmodel you need to count (date of birth) dob to date format, then count the gap to Date.now, and add another field remainingDays with the results. I hope it makes sense ;)